# JSONObject wont parse all the data from HTTP Post response

Tags: java, android, json

i am facing a problem that drive me crazy, i search in this site and in google and couldnt find any results.

i am building an app with android sdk that uses JSON parser.

i wrote code that handle the http post and i am getting the correct response but when i'm trying to parse it into JSONObject using:

strJson -> the response from the server.

JSONobject json = new JSONObject(strJson)

its not parsing all the data and some objects are blank(null pointer)

i checked the json response with many tools (including jsonlint.com) and its valid

what is the problem?

BTW this is the json response:

```
{
"tag": "login",
"success": 1,
"error": 0,
"userprofile": {
    "0": "123",
    "1": "0",
    "2": "mock@g.com",
    "3": "e807f1fcf82d132f9bb018ca6738a19f",
    "4": "misha",
    "5": "user",
    "6": "2000-05-22",
    "7": "264",
    "8": "Ben Gurion, Engineer",
    "9": "female",
    "10": "female",
    "11": "unemployed",
    "12": "Sillicon Vally, USA",
    "13": "english",
    "14": "hi i am new to heyou",
    "15": "1",
    "16": "2012-04-15 11:11:29",
    "user_id": "123",
    "facebook_id": "0",
    "email": "mock@g.com",
    "password": "e807f1fcf82d132f9bb018ca6738a19f",
    "firstname": "misha",
    "lastname": "user",
    "dob": "2000-05-22",
    "points": "264",
    "study": "Ben Gurion, Engineer",
    "gender": "female",
    "intrested": "female",
    "profession": "unemployed",
    "location": "Sillicon Vally, USA",
    "knows": "english",
    "status": "hi i am new to heyou",
    "activated": "1",
    "created": "2012-04-15 11:11:29"
},
"userpictures": {
    "0": {
        "0": "1",
        "1": "123",
        "2": "profile",
        "3": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-ash2/372237_100000725612104_1712537362_n.jpg",
        "4": "2012-04-23 01:51:15",
        "node_id": "1",
        "user_id": "123",
        "type": "profile",
        "path": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-ash2/372237_100000725612104_1712537362_n.jpg",
        "updated": "2012-04-23 01:51:15"
    },
    "tag": "getpictures",
    "success": 0,
    "error": 0,
    "user_id": "123",
    "numberofpictures": 1
},
"userfriends": {
    "0": {
        "user_id": "456",
        "name": "aksjdkasjdkasjdk ",
        "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/369825_1446671611_369000795_n.jpg",
        "online": "1",
        "longitude": "32.5568774",
        "lawtitude": "34.8789575",
        "address": "Israel ,Beersheva ,even susan",
        "client": "android"
    },
    "1": {
        "user_id": "789",
        "name": "naty ",
        "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/368727_1016960715_915310545_n.jpg",
        "online": "0",
        "longitude": "32.58964587",
        "lawtitude": "38.54578998",
        "address": "IRAQ ,Bagdad ,bag 9288",
        "client": "android"
    },
    "2": {
        "user_id": "4fa01f9e1d9243.41584266",
        "name": "matan ",
        "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-ash2/372237_100000725612104_1712537362_n.jpg",
        "online": "",
        "longitude": "",
        "lawtitude": "",
        "address": "",
        "client": ""
    },
    "3": {
        "user_id": "456",
        "name": "aksjdkasjdkasjdk ",
        "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/369825_1446671611_369000795_n.jpg",
        "online": "1",
        "longitude": "32.5568774",
        "lawtitude": "34.8789575",
        "address": "Israel ,Beersheva ,even susan",
        "client": "android"
    },
    "4": {
        "user_id": "789",
        "name": "naty ",
        "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/368727_1016960715_915310545_n.jpg",
        "online": "0",
        "longitude": "32.58964587",
        "lawtitude": "38.54578998",
        "address": "IRAQ ,Bagdad ,bag 9288",
        "client": "android"
    },
    "5": {
        "user_id": "789",
        "name": "naty ",
        "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/368727_1016960715_915310545_n.jpg",
        "online": "0",
        "longitude": "32.58964587",
        "lawtitude": "38.54578998",
        "address": "IRAQ ,Bagdad ,bag 9288",
        "client": "android"
    },
    "6": {
        "user_id": "456",
        "name": "aksjdkasjdkasjdk ",
        "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/369825_1446671611_369000795_n.jpg",
        "online": "1",
        "longitude": "32.5568774",
        "lawtitude": "34.8789575",
        "address": "Israel ,Beersheva ,even susan",
        "client": "android"
    },
    "7": {
        "user_id": "456",
        "name": "aksjdkasjdkasjdk ",
        "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/369825_1446671611_369000795_n.jpg",
        "online": "1",
        "longitude": "32.5568774",
        "lawtitude": "34.8789575",
        "address": "Israel ,Beersheva ,even susan",
        "client": "android"
    },
    "8": {
        "user_id": "789",
        "name": "naty ",
        "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/368727_1016960715_915310545_n.jpg",
        "online": "0",
        "longitude": "32.58964587",
        "lawtitude": "38.54578998",
        "address": "IRAQ ,Bagdad ,bag 9288",
        "client": "android"
    },
    "9": {
        "user_id": "456",
        "name": "aksjdkasjdkasjdk ",
        "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/369825_1446671611_369000795_n.jpg",
        "online": "1",
        "longitude": "32.5568774",
        "lawtitude": "34.8789575",
        "address": "Israel ,Beersheva ,even susan",
        "client": "android"
    },
    "10": {
        "user_id": "123",
        "name": "misha ",
        "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-ash2/372237_100000725612104_1712537362_n.jpg",
        "online": "0",
        "longitude": "23",
        "lawtitude": "54",
        "address": " ,asdkasjd ,asdasd",
        "client": "android"
    },
    "11": {
        "user_id": "789",
        "name": "naty ",
        "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/368727_1016960715_915310545_n.jpg",
        "online": "0",
        "longitude": "32.58964587",
        "lawtitude": "38.54578998",
        "address": "IRAQ ,Bagdad ,bag 9288",
        "client": "android"
    },
    "12": {
        "user_id": "789",
        "name": "naty ",
        "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/368727_1016960715_915310545_n.jpg",
        "online": "0",
        "longitude": "32.58964587",
        "lawtitude": "38.54578998",
        "address": "IRAQ ,Bagdad ,bag 9288",
        "client": "android"
    },
    "13": {
        "user_id": "789",
        "name": "naty ",
        "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/368727_1016960715_915310545_n.jpg",
        "online": "0",
        "longitude": "32.58964587",
        "lawtitude": "38.54578998",
        "address": "IRAQ ,Bagdad ,bag 9288",
        "client": "android"
    },
    "14": {
        "user_id": "456",
        "name": "aksjdkasjdkasjdk ",
        "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/369825_1446671611_369000795_n.jpg",
        "online": "1",
        "longitude": "32.5568774",
        "lawtitude": "34.8789575",
        "address": "Israel ,Beersheva ,even susan",
        "client": "android"
    },
    "15": {
        "user_id": "123",
        "name": "misha ",
        "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-ash2/372237_100000725612104_1712537362_n.jpg",
        "online": "0",
        "longitude": "23",
        "lawtitude": "54",
        "address": " ,asdkasjd ,asdasd",
        "client": "android"
    },
    "16": {
        "user_id": "789",
        "name": "naty ",
        "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/368727_1016960715_915310545_n.jpg",
        "online": "0",
        "longitude": "32.58964587",
        "lawtitude": "38.54578998",
        "address": "IRAQ ,Bagdad ,bag 9288",
        "client": "android"
    },
    "17": {
        "user_id": "789",
        "name": "naty ",
        "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/368727_1016960715_915310545_n.jpg",
        "online": "0",
        "longitude": "32.58964587",
        "lawtitude": "38.54578998",
        "address": "IRAQ ,Bagdad ,bag 9288",
        "client": "android"
    },
    "18": {
        "user_id": "789",
        "name": "naty ",
        "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/368727_1016960715_915310545_n.jpg",
        "online": "0",
        "longitude": "32.58964587",
        "lawtitude": "38.54578998",
        "address": "IRAQ ,Bagdad ,bag 9288",
        "client": "android"
    },
    "tag": "getfriendlist",
    "success": 1,
    "user_id": "123",
    "numberoffriends": 19
},
"usergoods": {
    "0": {
        "0": "123",
        "1": "Burger",
        "2": "Eat some burger",
        "3": "Gifts",
        "4": "25",
        "5": "25",
        "6": "http://www.pythagorapps.com/heyou/gifts/123.png",
        "7": null,
        "8": "2012-05-07 01:25:53",
        "product_id": "123",
        "product_name": "Burger",
        "product_desc": "Eat some burger",
        "category": "Gifts",
        "product_price": "25",
        "product_points": "25",
        "path": "http://www.pythagorapps.com/heyou/gifts/123.png",
        "locale": null,
        "created": "2012-05-07 01:25:53"
    },
    "1": {
        "0": "456",
        "1": "Beer",
        "2": "Drink ice cold beer",
        "3": "Gifts",
        "4": "30",
        "5": "30",
        "6": "http://www.pythagorapps.com/heyou/gifts/456.png",
        "7": null,
        "8": "2012-05-07 01:25:53",
        "product_id": "456",
        "product_name": "Beer",
        "product_desc": "Drink ice cold beer",
        "category": "Gifts",
        "product_price": "30",
        "product_points": "30",
        "path": "http://www.pythagorapps.com/heyou/gifts/456.png",
        "locale": null,
        "created": "2012-05-07 01:25:53"
    },
    "2": {
        "0": "789",
        "1": "Coctail",
        "2": "Drink a refreshing coctail",
        "3": "Gifts",
        "4": "50",
        "5": "50",
        "6": "http://www.pythagorapps.com/heyou/gifts/789.png",
        "7": null,
        "8": "2012-05-10 04:56:18",
        "product_id": "789",
        "product_name": "Coctail",
        "product_desc": "Drink a refreshing coctail",
        "category": "Gifts",
        "product_price": "50",
        "product_points": "50",
        "path": "http://www.pythagorapps.com/heyou/gifts/789.png",
        "locale": null,
        "created": "2012-05-10 04:56:18"
    },
    "tag": "getgoods",
    "success": 1,
    "error": 0,
    "numofgoods": 3
},
"useravatar": {
    "tag": "getlatest",
    "success": 0,
    "error": 10,
    "err_msg": "cannot connect to mySQL database"
},
"shopcategories": {
    "0": {
        "0": "1",
        "1": "Shirts",
        "2": "Buy some cool new shirts",
        "3": "null",
        "4": "2012-05-07 01:09:02",
        "index": "1",
        "name": "Shirts",
        "desc": "Buy some cool new shirts",
        "path": "null",
        "created": "2012-05-07 01:09:02"
    },
    "1": {
        "0": "2",
        "1": "Gifts",
        "2": "buy some cool gifts",
        "3": "null",
        "4": "2012-05-07 01:09:58",
        "index": "2",
        "name": "Gifts",
        "desc": "buy some cool gifts",
        "path": "null",
        "created": "2012-05-07 01:09:58"
    },
    "tag": "getcat",
    "success": 1,
    "error": 0,
    "numofcat": 2
},
"shopproducts": {
    "0": {
        "0": "123",
        "1": "Burger",
        "2": "Eat some burger",
        "3": "Gifts",
        "4": "25",
        "5": "25",
        "6": "http://www.pythagorapps.com/heyou/gifts/123.png",
        "7": null,
        "8": "2012-05-07 01:25:53",
        "product_id": "123",
        "product_name": "Burger",
        "product_desc": "Eat some burger",
        "category": "Gifts",
        "product_price": "25",
        "product_points": "25",
        "path": "http://www.pythagorapps.com/heyou/gifts/123.png",
        "locale": null,
        "created": "2012-05-07 01:25:53"
    },
    "1": {
        "0": "456",
        "1": "Beer",
        "2": "Drink ice cold beer",
        "3": "Gifts",
        "4": "30",
        "5": "30",
        "6": "http://www.pythagorapps.com/heyou/gifts/456.png",
        "7": null,
        "8": "2012-05-07 01:25:53",
        "product_id": "456",
        "product_name": "Beer",
        "product_desc": "Drink ice cold beer",
        "category": "Gifts",
        "product_price": "30",
        "product_points": "30",
        "path": "http://www.pythagorapps.com/heyou/gifts/456.png",
        "locale": null,
        "created": "2012-05-07 01:25:53"
    },
    "2": {
        "0": "789",
        "1": "Coctail",
        "2": "Drink a refreshing coctail",
        "3": "Gifts",
        "4": "50",
        "5": "50",
        "6": "http://www.pythagorapps.com/heyou/gifts/789.png",
        "7": null,
        "8": "2012-05-10 04:56:18",
        "product_id": "789",
        "product_name": "Coctail",
        "product_desc": "Drink a refreshing coctail",
        "category": "Gifts",
        "product_price": "50",
        "product_points": "50",
        "path": "http://www.pythagorapps.com/heyou/gifts/789.png",
        "locale": null,
        "created": "2012-05-10 04:56:18"
    },
    "tag": "getall",
    "success": 1,
    "error": 0,
    "numofproducts": 3,
    "user_id": "123"
}
}
```

BTW 2:

the iOS app seem to parse it correctly.

thanks in advance.

EDIT:

my code to get the response is:

```
    public JSONObject getJSONFromURL(String URL,List<NameValuePair> params){

    //try to make http request:

    try{
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL+listToString(params));
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();
    }
    catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(ClientProtocolException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    //try to read the respond:

    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
            sb.append(line+"\n");
        }
        is.close();
        strJson = sb.toString();
        Log.e("JSON",strJson);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("Buffer Error","Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    //try to parse the string to JSON object:
    try{
        json = new JSONObject(strJson);
    }
    catch(JSONException e){
        Log.e("JSON Parser","Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    return json;

}
```

the json returned json object is missing some objects like userprofiles, success, etc...

but the strJson is valid!

Comment: Are not missing the "[" "]" when it starts the JSONArrays?

Comment: Does the line >>"user_id": "4fa01f9e1d9243.41584266",<< cause some of your problems?  All your other `user_id` fields are three decimal digits.

Comment: It seems that you missed "}" at the end of the object.

Comment: @parvin no he doesn't, the missing "}" is below the syntax highlighting

Comment: Kindly go through this link: http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/

Comment: Ok,sorry...I didn't see that.

Answer (score 0):

> > String value = (String) jsonserch2.opt(key);

Try this when object ha null value it automatically reject it
instead **jsonserch2.getString(key)**;

Comment: There is no problem getting a specific key-value, the problem is that the entire "userprofile" object is missing, insted of it there is NULL pointer

Comment: Thank you for your replies,
but the problem was the name of the objects...

i guess that they were too long

changing "userprofile" to "profile" fixed the problem and now the Android json parser works like charm.

this is wired considering that iOS and many other validation tools didn't face that problem.